# Plugin with id 'Android' cannot be found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I've done a gradle export of an old project of mine from eclipse and

> imported it into android studio. I get the error: Plugin with id
>   'Android' cannot be found

I've found a few references to this error but the suggestions didnt work for me, below is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':Panic Phase 2:PanicPhase2:PanicAndroid:facebook-android-sdk-master:facebook')
    compile project(':google_play_services:libproject:google-play-services_lib')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 11
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you got the Gradle plugin identifier wrong.

Try replacing `apply plugin: 'android'` with `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

Answer (score 0):

This `build.gradle` is wrong.

**First of all change:**

```
  apply plugin: 'android'
```

to

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

**Then remove** the `classpath` from the `dependencies` block:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':Panic Phase 2:PanicPhase2:PanicAndroid:facebook-android-sdk-master:facebook')
    compile project(':google_play_services:libproject:google-play-services_lib')
}
```

**Finally add** a `buildscript` block with your classpath for android plugin.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+' 
    }
}
```

**Pay attention.**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'
```

is an old plugin.
You should use

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
```

It may require to update the version of gradle.
You can do that by editing the file `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties:`

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```